# Use saveInstanceState with Uri ArrayList and adapter

Tags: java, android, bundle, android-arrayadapter

I created a list view that uploads files from sd card to  and attaches it within the list. Yet I back out of the activity and onDestroyed gets called and I lose all my data from my listView.  I am using An ArrayList FileUploaded  and adapter to upload the files but I am confused on how I can implement that on "onSavedInstanceState" method.

I've done research but I am still having some issues.

Am I storing the wrong Items?

Please help... any advice at all.

My Variables:

```
ListView Added_Files;
Button Select_File;
Button Add_To_List;
Button Save_Button;
Button Add_To_DropBox;
TextView selectedFile;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
ArrayList<Uri> FileUpload = new ArrayList<Uri>();
ArrayAdapter  adapter;
```

//method that adds the file to listView when button "Upload to List" is clicked

```
 public void addList(){

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,FileUpload);
    Add_To_List.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Added_Files.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.add(uri.getPath());
            ((BaseAdapter) Added_Files.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            selectedFile.setText("");
            Make_File_Empty();

           // Toast.makeText(AddFiles.this, "File Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Here is the method when file on sd card is selected and displays it on the screen

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            //If file selection was successfull
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    //get uri of the selected file
                    uri = data.getData();

                    Log.i(TAG, "Uri = " + uri.toString());
                    try {
                        //get file path from Uri
                       // Toast.makeText(AddFiles.this, "File Selected: " + uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        selectedFile.setText("Selected File: " + uri.getPath());

                        addList();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("FileSelectorActivity", "File select error", e);
                    }
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the onSaved/restore methods:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("key",FileUpload );
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    FileUpload = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("key");
}
```

Comment: you can store those in sqlite and show them in listActivity again

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: What can SQLite do differently? and how would I be able to implement the files?  I'm not sure which files I should store... the ArrayList? Uri? the adapter?

Comment: store the path of the files.

Comment: What exactly would the path be?  I used uri.getPath to obtain the details of the file, is that what you mean?

Comment: If there was some sort of example code on how I can get started on it, I think it would really help a lot. I am just confused about storing and restoring data when there are several different components...

Comment: What am I doing wrong with my code? Am I getting the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a careful look at this article: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#save-simple-lightweight-ui-state-using-onsaveinstancestate

It looks like in `onSaveInstanceState` you're saving your state after calling super, which might cause the data to not get saved. You also might want to save and restore the text in your TextView so it's shown when the UI is restored.

Another thing to note is what it says here:`Note: onSaveInstanceState() is not called when the user explicitly closes the activity or in other cases when finish()is called.`

Saving state is only intended to save data in short term situations (the example saves it before calling super), if you want to save it for longer (between app launches) you might want to use a SQLite database which is a lot more complicated.

I'm not an expert at this stuff specifically but hope this helped! I'd recommend setting breakpoints in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` to see what is being called when if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Thank you! Ill take a look at SQLite database.   When you said "
you're saving your state after calling super, which might cause the data to not get saved. "  do you mean I should just write what I had before super?  as well as saving the textViews of the Uri? ...Is what I had look okay? is that how it should be written?  Should I also be saving the adapter? because I have the arrayList, adapter, textView, and Uri... Im just a bit overwhelmed on the data that needs to be saved.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. For the text views, you only need to save the text that's in them. You're on the right track but it would be easier to start with a simpler example (separate project) to get it working and expand from there. Just take your time and focus on learning about the functionality :)